# JUnit fail test : expected:<sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl@48030df0> but was:<sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl@40882c7f>

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

### I have this error when I run my unit test (assertEquals):

### java.lang.AssertionError: expected:sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl@48030df0> but was:sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl@40882c7f>

when I run my unit test for this code to test getSslSocketFactory method

```
public ClientCertSocketFactory() throws IOException{
    String trustStoreFilePath = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
    try {
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = CertManagerFactory.loadTrustStore(trustStoreFilePath);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        this.sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        LOGGER.error("No Provider supports a TrustManagerFactorySpi implementation for the TLS protocol. Error message: " + e);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occurred when initializing SSLContext. Error message: " + e);
    }
}

public SSLSocketFactory getSslSocketFactory() {
    return sslSocketFactory;
}
```

---

### My unit test for getSslSocketFactory is:

```
@Test
public void shouldGetSslSocketFactory() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException{
    String trustStoreFilePath = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");

    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = CertManagerFactory.loadTrustStore(trustStoreFilePath);
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
    this.sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    assertEquals(sslSocketFactory, clientCertSocketFactory.getSslSocketFactory());


}
```

How I can fix it ?
Thanks  a lot

Comment: This is not an answer, but to be clear, what you have here is not a "unit test". You are not verifying your application business logic, you're verifying the integration of your code with the underlying SSL framework.  It's nonsensical to write a unit test for a "getter" method, as you're stating here.

Comment: You might consider stepping through both of these functions in your debugger and examining where something unexpected happens.

Comment: How would this ever be equal? After you reconfigure your trust manager, you get another instance of a in return, thus the test fails. (Those are equal by identity.)